# Ubuntu GNOME вместо Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

Может кто подскажет, есть ли наиболее удобный способ переустановить linux. Стоит версия Ubuntu 16.04, хочу поставить Ubuntu GNOME. У кого какие идеи, или кто-нибудь уже пытался и делал подобное? Спасибо

Comment: А кто мешает держать на винте несколько DE?

Comment: мне один нужен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, поменять дистрибутив удалось только полной переустановкой линукса, сама замена оболочки не помогла.

Answer (score 0):

поставьте пакет [gnome](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gnome/gnome):

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome
```

и на экране авторизации пользователя выберите нужный сеанс. как именно выглядит в вашем dm (их вообще-то много) кнопка для выбора сеанса могу сказать только ориентировочно: что-нибудь вроде шестерёнки или буквальной надписи «выбрать сессию».

Comment: пока не могу проверить, но, это установит полностью заново весь линукс или чисто внешнюю оболочку?

Comment: нет, программу linux это действие никак не затронет.

Comment: я к чему это все, устанавливал убунту, вроде все норм сперва было, потом просто так начинал виснуть комп, что даже не реагировал на кнопу на ноуте "Выключить", потом я перед установкой зашел "Дополнительный" раздел и проверил на ошибки и удалил всякий шлак, который он нашел, эта проблема вроде ушла, дальше почему-то после установки Webstorm в списке установленных программ она не отображается и поиск не находит, вот и подумал, что может я криво поставил и заодно установил бы другой дистрибутив

Answer (score 0):

Если перевстановить то все гораздо проще:
[Качаем офицальный Ubuntu Gnome](https://ubuntugnome.org/download/)

Устанавливаем.

Welcome to Gnome!

Answer (score -1):

Удаление *Unity*:

```
$ sudo apt remove unity8-desktop-session-mir && apt autoremove && apt -f install
```

Установка *Gnome*:

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Comment: не удалось открыть файл блокировки /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (Отказано  доступе). И спрашивает есть ли у меня права пользователя

Comment: попробуй это решить так: $ sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Comment: в первой команде вы дважды программу *sudo* пропустили.

Comment: нет, я внимательно пишу команды

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich, мой комментарий адресовался не вам, а автору ответа. у него в ответе отсутствие двух sudo — не единственная ошибка: ещё у программы `apt` нет опции `-f` (по крайней мере до версии из xenial). там подразумевалась программа `apt-get`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вот так получается: `$ sudo apt remove unity8-desktop-session-mir && sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt-get install` ?

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich, да я б вообще-то не рекомендовал следовать инструкции, изложенной в этом ответе. по крайней мере дословно.

Comment: У топикстартера значится Ubuntu 16.04, там у apt есть опция -f. Что касается дважды "пропущенного" sudo - каждый раз вводить не обязательно. Вся цепочка команд выполняется от суперпользователя.